# How can I find out about the latest updates to Cortana?

Tags: update, cortana

As an avid WP user, I really enjoy Cortana (even though it's not available in my language and I've set my region to the wrong setting just to be able to use it). I I like that I really use it and it makes performing some tasks less tedious. Every once in a while, new features are added to it.

I've read up about what [I can say](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/cortana/what-can-i-say-to-cortana), and check that list every once in a while. The problem is, I don't know if that list gets updated or if it does; when.

Is there a change log for the features of Cortana? I've found [this](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/cortana/whats-new-in-cortana), but it's more of a blog post than a real (developer) change log. Is there something similar which shows me list of updates sorted by version and date and their updates (or added features) to Cortana?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an official change log at the moment. I would recommend keeping an eye on the Windows Central's Cortana page. It's currently the most reliable source for finding out about new Cortana features IMHO.
http://windowscentral.com/cortana